# TinyMCE insert wrong code

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm trying to insert video to an article. I'm using TinyMCE. For example I want to insert video with url http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 and HTML5 type. Tiny generates code

```
<video width="320" height="240" preload="none" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
    <object width="320" height="240" data="/media/editors/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param name="src" value="/media/editors/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="url=http%3A//techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4&amp;poster=/" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="true" />
    </object>
</video>
```

It doesn't show video player.
There is no console errors. Urls to .js scripts are correct.
What's wrong?

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me with TinyMce, but I don't have the same results. Instead of :
`<video width="320" height="240" preload="none" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">`
I have this 2 lines :
`<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" name="media">
<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />`
Maybe you have to configure tinyMCE (extensions/manage plug-in and filter to find tinyMCE, mine is set to extended), or install a more permissive and configurable editor like JCE

Comment: It's necessery to check "Controls" in "Advanced" tab and works well.